# printing format in python - expected left allignment

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting, output

I have a function that basically takes in a dictionary with a list of values for each key and it processes the dictionary to get the total count of values for each key and then it sorts them based on keys.

code:

```
def friends_count(candidate):
    di = {k:sum(1 for x in v if x) for k,v in candidate.items()}
    for key in sorted(di): print "%s %s" % (key,di[key])
```

[image: My output]

Expected Output:

[image]

How do I left allign my output ??
Can anyone suggest me some print statement alternative ??

Comment: Almost all of those candidates are already "right aligned" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.rjust(width, " ")`, where `width` is bigger than the longest name:

```
def friends_count(candidate):
    di = {k:sum(1 for x in v if x) for k,v in candidate.items()}
    for key in sorted(di): print "%s %s" % (key.rjust(20," "),str(di[key]).rjust(4," "))
```

Comment: I didn't get you.. can you explain further, i'm actually new to python

Comment: oh i'm sorry . how do i left allign the output ? mistyped my question

Comment: You can use `ljust` the same way you would use `rjust`